# Modal reopen after two click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, state

I try to create a modal on a login screen but i have a weird issue. When i click on the button for open the modal it open as well and i can close it too. But when i want to Re-open the modal i have to click 2 times on the button for it open again.

Here my code:

Login screen:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";
import { globalStyles } from "../styles/globalStyles";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import LogModal from "../components/LogModal";

const Login = () => {
  const [openToggle, setOpenToggle] = useState(false);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setOpenToggle((prev) => !prev);
  };

  return (
    <LinearGradient colors={["#000", "#fff"]} style={globalStyles.container}>
      <View style={globalStyles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={globalStyles.title}>HGDZ</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={globalStyles.logo}>
        <Ionicons name="md-ice-cream-outline" size={80} color="white" />
      </View>
      <View style={globalStyles.btnLogContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={globalStyles.touchable} onPress={handleToggle}>
          <View style={globalStyles.btnContainer}>
            <Text style={globalStyles.btnLogText}>S'incrire</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={globalStyles.touchable} onPress={handleToggle}>
          <View style={globalStyles.btnContainer}>
            <Text style={globalStyles.btnLogText}>Connexion</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <LogModal open={openToggle} />
    </LinearGradient>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Modal component:

```
import React, { useState, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Modal, Pressable, Alert } from "react-native";
import { globalStyles } from "../styles/globalStyles";

const LogModal = (props) => {
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    setModalVisible(props.open);
  }, [props]);

  const handleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible((prev) => !prev);
    console.log(modalVisible);
  };

  return (
    <View style={globalStyles.centeredView}>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={true}
        visible={modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => {
          Alert.alert("Modal has been closed.");
          setModalVisible(!modalVisible);
        }}
      >
        <View style={globalStyles.centeredView}>
          <View style={styles.modalView}>
            <Text style={styles.modalText}>Hello World!</Text>
            <Pressable
              style={[styles.button, styles.buttonClose]}
              onPress={() => setModalVisible((prev) => !prev)}
            >
              <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hide Modal</Text>
            </Pressable>
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centeredView: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 22,
  },
  modalView: {
    marginTop: "50%",
    margin: 20,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 35,
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 4,
    elevation: 5,
  },
  button: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    padding: 10,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  buttonOpen: {
    backgroundColor: "#F194FF",
  },
  buttonClose: {
    backgroundColor: "#2196F3",
  },
  textStyle: {
    color: "white",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  modalText: {
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});

export default LogModal;
```

I don't see where i made mistake an y advice?

Comment: You're using two states from two components to manage the open property. Use one or the other. Either hold the "open" state in the parent, and pass down the state and a function to toggle it to the `LogModal` component, or let `LogModal` manage it completely independently.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i manage to apply it and it works!